# iPhone app issue: UIImageView sequence not loading

Tags: iphone, xcode

First off, I am just starting with Xcode and iPhone developing, so please bear with me if these issues are redundant...I haven't found the answer yet, hence my posting. Second...ok, there is second...so I will get to the question.

I am using an UIImage view for the background image of my TheEyeViewController and I need another UIImageView to set on top of the background UIImageView. The foreground UIImageView needs to load a sequence of images...but it's not working. When I try to setup the foreground image view with code, I don't think the compiler is able to differentiate between the 2 image views. It doesn't crash...the sequence just doesn't show up.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your time.

//.h

UIImageView *imageView;

@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

```
//.m

- (void)viewDidLoad

{

 imageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"openingSeq1.jpg"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"openingSeq2.jpg"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"openingSeq3.jpg"],
                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"openingSeq4.jpg"],
                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"openingSeq5.jpg"],
                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"openingSeq6.jpg"],
                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"openingSeq7.jpg"],
                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"openingSeq8.jpg"],
                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"openingSeq9.jpg"],
                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"openingSeq10.jpg"],nil];

    imageView.animationDuration = 2;
    imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1;
    [imageView startAnimating];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

if(imageView.image == nil)
    {
        labelRandText.text = @"Images didn't load.";
    }

```
    [super viewDidLoad];

}
```

Comment: Can you post the code that's failing? Also interesting in this case would be your class header definition, especially the parts that define each UIImageView. Finally, make sure your Interface Builder outlets are connected properly.

Comment: Also, as a StackOverflow note, you should consider a more descriptive title. Something like 'loading sequence of images to UIImageView fails', for example.

Comment: Can you check if imageView is not nil? Something like `if(!imageView) NSLog(@"There's no ImageView!");`

Comment: I added an if statement and it says that the images did not load.

Comment: Could it be that the naming conventions with 2 image view controls are at odds? Is the compiler looking at the 2 and considers it one control?

Comment: I FOUND IT! THANKS ALL FOR THE HELP!

Answer (score 1):

General comments that may or may not help:

Supposing `[UIImage imageNamed:@"openingSeq1.jpg"]` returns nil, that's the same as posting an empty array because that nil will look like the one that ends the list of things passed to `arrayWithObjects:`. It's probably worth adding a quick:

```
NSLog(@"os1: %@", [UIImage imageNamed:@"openingSeq1.jpg"]);
```

If that shows that you're getting nil back then your project is set up incorrectly, such that UIImage can't find the files.

If imageView is already in your view in Interface Builder then `[self.view addSubview:imageView];` is redundant, but shouldn't be harmful.

An `NSLog(@"%@", imageView)` (or even one that logs both the imageView you're trying to reach and the other one that you think may be problematic, so you can check they're not the same one) can be used to verify that you have things wired up correctly in Interface Builder.

Also, technically you should call `[super viewDidLoad];` before any of your own code, because logically you want the superclass to have done whatever it should do before you do whatever you should do. However, as with addSubview, this shouldn't really make any odds in your particular case because the UIViewController base class doesn't do anything in viewDidLoad.